# DB2 REGEXP_LIKE unable to recognize dash in field data

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange, regexp-like

I have the following DB2 for i series REGEXP_LIKE expression that is treating the minus sign, or hyphen, or dash, or whatever you want to call it,  as some kind of special character and does not work as intended. I need to find all **ITEMNAME** that end in a "**-C**", or "**-DC**", or "**-IC**". The "-DC$" and "-IC$" work great. The "-C$" will not work. Even with an "escape" character of "backwards slash" or the dollar sign "$" to match a pattern at the end of the string.

REGEXP_LIKE(ITEMNAMES, '-C$|-DC$|-IC$', 'i')

I also tried the "flag" value of "m" without success. Just the "-C" works, but it returns results with a "-C" in the middle of a data field. I only want the ones ending with a "-C".

Also the "-C" does not work in a LIKE command to find the matching pattern either.

Comment: `SELECT *
FROM (VALUES 'ABC-C') T (ITEMNAMES)
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(ITEMNAMES, '-C$|-DC$|-IC$', 'i')`. This returns a row on my v7.4. What's your exact DB2 version?

Comment: try to isolate the regex which is not working. Run the query with `REGEXP_LIKE(ITEMNAMES, '-C$', 'i')`.  Then try the REGEXP_LIKE function with all the patterns OR REGEXP_LIKE with just the -C$ pattern.

Comment: FYI - OS is V7R3, DB2 is 10.5